# Would gravity be noticeable without physical charge?

Tags: physics

I answered a question on the physics site about the difference between the classical notion of gravitational force and the notion in general relativity. I answered that the force used in the Newtonian notion is actually the electromagnetic force. It was thought I am a subscriber to the electric universe model...Which, despite its attractive dissident nature, I'm actually not.

I conjectured that in fact all other three forces facilitate gravity to be felt. Think about it. If all charge would be gone and only mass was left (which is kind of self contradicting as mass needs charge) all particles would fall to each other without opposing forces and all force left would be the tidal force.

An object falling to Earth feels no force. It's actually us accelerating upwards by the EM force.

Any thoughts?

Edit
In other words, could you observe second order effects only? So not the first order effect of, say, a mass falling on the surface of the Earth, which apparently diminishes the distance between the mass and the surface of the Earth, while in fact the decreasing distance is due to the electromagnetic force pushing the surface upward. Without this force (caused by electric charge), the surface would freely fall to the center of mass. The distances between particles falling freely to the CoM increase only due to the tidal force, locally. Non-locally (i.e., globally), the distance between particles on opposite sides of the CoM decreases, as expected for an attractive force. It's the question if a solid CoM can get realized in the first place, without the three basic forces and associated charges (electric, color, hypercolor). The distances between the CoM and falling particles would decrease, but what if there is no real solid surface to fall on?

Imagine a spherical cloud of particles with mass only. All particles would fall to the imaginary CoM, of course. Locally the distances between the particles stays approximately the same or increases non-linearly due to the tidal force (locally, it looks as if space expands; for example, particles falling into a black hole see particles in front of them and on the back of them accelerate away from them, as if space between them expands). Only opposing forces, i.e., charges, could actually make the local linear effects manifest.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135466/discussion-on-question-by-felicia-would-gravity-be-noticeable-without-physical-c).

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to discern exactly what you are asking here, but it is *not* mainstream physics as dealt with on the physics SE.

A useful rule of thumb is this: if the problem you are trying to solve cannot be expressed in a mathematical equation then whatever you are doing, it isn't physics. In that case it *might* be philosophy or it *might* be nonsense.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. It's quite unusual to rob particles of their charge... But hey, this is philosophy! If you wanna do the math, be my guest. Set all mass to zero in GR...